# What alphanumeric string length can be used to guarantee no hash collisions from CRC-64?

Tags: hash, crc

If I'm hashing alphanumeric strings (chars in the set `0`-`9`, `a`-`z`, and `A`-`Z`) with a CRC-64 hashing function, how long can my strings be while guaranteeing no hash collisions?

Stated differently: If I have a set of all CRC-64 checksums computed from alphanumeric strings  $0$ to $N$ bytes, how large can $N$ be before I see a collision in the set?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a non-cryptographic checksum function, not cryptography as we handle it here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have 62 chars you can transform 62 letters ($10+26+26$) in 6 bit number (approx). CRC is guaranteed to be unique mapping ([Injective function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective)) as long as input is shorter than output  – you can have at most 10 letters, but not 11 since $62^{10} < 2^{64} < 62^{11}$.

It same goes whit most other hash functions. Lets say that you have hash function that takes only 64 bits and makes 64 bit output and is bijective (like a symmetric cypher). That mean you will not have collision as long as your input is shorter than 64 bits.

If you have mappings from all 64 bit inputs you are 100% sure that each new input will produce collision (because there is no value that is unused)

Comment: wow... you blew my mind, is it true that CRC is an injective function?

Comment: CRC is guaranteed since it uses primitive polynomial. Primitive polynomials are generators of finite field and that mean that CRC can have any value between 1 and 2^N

Comment: Assuming a standard encoding of characters as 8 bit bytes you can guarantee uniqueness only up to 8 characters.

Comment: Attention: This 10-character limit is only valid in this form if you recode your 10 characters to 8 bytes (using something like base64?) before calculating the checksum.

Comment: @Paŭlo Base64 encoding requires 4 characters for every three bytes of the original value. You want to reverse-base64 it.

Comment: @configurator: Yes, I meant this (but didn't say so). Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @ralu's answer is correct *only* if the input is encoded in a special format, so that the encoding of the 10 letters fits within 64 bits.  That is not how inputs will normally be encoded, so ralu's answer is misleading and unlikely to apply to most practical situations.

Answer (score 6):

I have a different take on ralu's accepted answer and some of the comments thereafter.

Consider two $N$-bit data sequences which we think of as
polynomials 
$$D^{(1)}(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} D_i^{(1)}x^i 
~~\text{and}~~D^{(2)}(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{N=1} D_i^{(2)}x^i$$
where each $D_i^{(1)}$ and $D_i^{(2)}$ is $0$ or $1$. Let $M(x)$
of degree $64$ denote the CRC polynomial.  Actual CRC 
implementations for data communications have many bells and whistles
but let us assume that for hashing purposes, the simplest form
of CRC is used so that
the CRC check sums (or hashes) $R^{(1)}(x)$ and $R^{(2)}(x)$ of 
degree $63$ or less (and thus having $64$ bits) are
 are the remainders obtained by dividing $x^{64}D^{(1)}(x)$ and 
$x^{64}D^{(2)}(x)$ by $M(x)$.  Rememeber that this is polynomial division
over the binary field $\{0,1\}$ where addition (and subtraction) is the
Exclusive-OR operation $\oplus$. 
We thus have
$$\begin{align*}
x^{64}D^{(1)}(x) &= Q^{(1)}(x)M(x) \oplus R^{(1)}(x)\\
x^{64}D^{(2)}(x) &= Q^{(2)}(x)M(x) \oplus  R^{(2)}(x)
\end{align*}$$
where $Q^{(1)}(x)$ and $Q^{(2)}(x)$ are the quotients.
Adding these two equations, we have that
$$x^{64}\left[D^{(1)}(x)\oplus D^{(2)}(x)\right]
= \left[Q^{(1)}(x) \oplus Q^{(1)}(x)\right]M(x) 
\oplus \left[R^{(1)}(x) \oplus R^{(2)}(x)\right]
$$ 
It follows that if $R^{(1)}(x) = R^{(2)}(x)$ so that
$[R^{(1)}(x) \oplus R^{(2)}(x) = 0$, then it must
be that $D^{(1)}(x)\oplus D^{(2)}(x)$ is a multiple of $M(x)$.
Conversely, if $D^{(1)}(x)\oplus D^{(2)}(x)$ is a multiple of $M(x)$,
then so is 
$$x^{64}\left[D^{(1)}(x)\oplus D^{(2)}(x)\right]
\oplus \left[Q^{(1)}(x) \oplus Q^{(1)}(x)\right]M(x) 
 = \left[R^{(1)}(x) \oplus R^{(2)}(x)\right]$$
a multiple of $M(x)$, and therefore $R^{(1)}(x) \oplus R^{(2)}(x)$
of degree $63$ or less is a multiple of $M(x)$ of degree $64$.
Since this can happen only if $R^{(1)}(x) \oplus R^{(2)}(x) = 0$,
that is, $R^{(1)}(x) = R^{(2)}(x)$, we have the following.

> $D^{(1)}(x)$ and $D^{(2)}(x)$ hash to the same check sum,
>   that is, $R^{(1)}(x) = R^{(2)}(x)$, if and only if 
>   $D^{(1)}(x)$ and $D^{(2)}(x)$ differ by a multiple of $M(x)$

This result holds even if $D^{(1)}(x)$ and $D^{(2)}(x)$
are of different degrees if we zero-pad the shorter sequence 
with zeroes at the high-order end to make the sequences of equal
length.  But if the afore-mentioned bells and
whistles are included (e.g. complement the high-order two bytes before
commencing CRC calculations), then the result still holds for
equal length data sequences, but should not be applied blindly
when $D^{(1)}(x)$ and $D^{(2)}(x)$ are of different degrees:
some care is necessary.

For the simple case considered here, we have immediately
that 
$$\deg D^{(1)}(x) = \deg D^{(2)}(x) = N-1 \geq \deg M(x) = 64$$
and so if $N \leq 64$, we are guaranteed that no two sequences
hash to the same checksum.

---

Turning to further specifics and ralu's answer, each alphanumeric symbol
can have one of $62$ different values, and while it is possible to
map $11$ such symbols to $62^{11}$ different bit sequences
of lengths $64$ or less, it is much more convenient
to implement a symbol-by-symbol mapping into $6$-bit bytes
and create a degree-$65$ data sequence $D(x)$ of $66$ bits to be hashed.
The downside is that 
four sequences $D(x), D(x)\oplus M(x), D(x) \oplus xM(x)$, 
and $D(x)\oplus
(1\oplus x)M(x)$ will have the same hash, and this is the price
paid for simplicity of the mapping algorithm: we have to restrict
ourselves to $10$ alphanumeric symbols to avoid collisions.
On the other hand, compressing $11$ alphanumeric symbols to
$64$ bits or less is a messy task.

An even simpler method is to use the password as entered by
the user (say as a sequence of ASCII-encoded $8$-bit bytes) to create
the data sequence by concatenation.  Now, $8$ symbols guarantees
no collisions as per the simplified analysis above, but the
actual picture is somewhat different.  Although with $9$ bytes
and $72$ bits, collisions *can* occur, it is not immediately
obvious that collisions *will* occur.  For example, $D(x)\oplus M(x)$
might well be a sequence of bytes that cannot be entered by
the user as a password because some of the ASCII characters are
control characters that cause the computer to take other actions
than to simply pass the character on to the application to be
processed.

I doubt there is a simple answer to the question of what is
the maximum password length for which collisions are guaranteed
not to occur.  The answer depends on the choice of $M(x)$
also.  For example, 
[Wikipedia's page on CRCs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check)
says that CRC-64-ISO $x^{64}+x^4+x^3+x+1$ is weak for hashing purposes,
the basis of which claim the diligent reader of the above will have no difficulty 
understanding.

Answer (score 5):

I will assume that the question is "If we take the CRC-64 function, and consider inputs that consist only of the ASCII characters in the specified range, what's the longest inputs we can have without having a collision".  The other answers assumed some mapping between the string and the CRC-64 function (and try to answer 'what sort of mapping would be best'); I'll assume that there is no such mapping.

Well, the full answer depends on the CRC polynomial, if we assume the CRC-64-ISO polynomial of $x^{64} + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1$, then I believe that the longest is 8.

We know that it is at least 8, because (as mentioned earlier) CRC's are guarranteed to have an output differential if the input differential is no longer than the CRC.

However, if we are allowed to inputs of length 9, then we can find collisions.

If the CRC-64 processes MSBits first, then:

CRC64(BxxxxxxxP) == CRC64(CxxxxxxxK)

This is because $B \oplus C = 0x42 \oplus 0x43 = 0x01$, which corresponds to the polynomial $x^{64}$ and $P \oplus K = 0x50 \oplus 0x4B = 0x1B$ which corresponds to the polynomial $x^{4} + x^{3} + x + 1$, and hence the bit-wise difference between the two inputs is exactly a multiple of the CRC polynomial (in fact, is precisely the CRC polynomial).

If the CRC-64 processes LSBits first, then:

CRC64(AxxxxxxxP) == CRC64(QxxxxxxxK)

This is because $A \oplus Q = 0x41 \oplus 0x51 = 0x10$ which corresponds to the polynomial $x^{67}$ and $P \oplus K = 0x50 \oplus 0x4B = 0x1B$ which corresponds to the polynomial $x^7 + x^6 + x^4 + x^3$ (this differs from the first example because we're counting bits from the other side of the byte), and hence the bit-wise difference between the two inputs is again an exact multiple of the CRC polynomial (in this case, $x^3$ times the CRC polynomial).

Answer (score -1):

This is classical [Birthday paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) problem and the linked Wikipedia article has a nice set of approximations that help you evaluate the chance of collisions. Of course, this applies to random choice of strings only. It's not possible to guarantee against collisions even when two strings are involved - there will be some very low probability even for two strings.

Comment: I can estimate that a collision is probable when N is greater than log(2^32)/log(62), or 5.374 characters, however I was looking for a guarantee.  For example, if I take all single characters in this set and a null string, I can verify that there are no collisions.  I'm guessing the only way to answer this is a brute-force test, but I'm hoping there's some literature out there that talks about collisions with a reduced input domain. any ideas?

Comment: @brandx: You have two paths. Path 1 is to search for analysis of CRC64 specifically - maybe one can strictly prove something given how CRC64 works under the hood and how it treats data. Path 2 is to assume that CRC64 is like a crypto hash - hashes anything into random-looking stuff and then you can't have a guarantee unless you test an exact string set.

Comment: @sharptooth, the issue is that CRC does not actually behave like a crypto hash, so Path 2 is not valid in this context; it will give you inaccurate results.