# SHA-512 hash collisions

Tags: collision-resistance, sha-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is SHA-512 bijective when hashing a single 512-bit block?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/301/is-sha-512-bijective-when-hashing-a-single-512-bit-block)

Is there any guarantee that there are no collisions for all 512-bit input values for SHA-512 (every 512-bit input has a unique output), or just that they are highly improbable and can't be algorithmically deduced?

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography Stack Exchange. I closed your question as we had a quite similar one (with a good answer) a time ago - the answer is essentially, no, for both parts of your question.

Comment: It's highly probable that they exist, they're just hard to find.