# Is SHA-1 collision free on data up to 20 bytes long?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, sha-1

Is SHA-1 collision free on data up to 20 bytes long (lenght of hash / internal state)? That means that every input produce unique output, but you surely know that, i just write it in order my question to be accepted by the site :)

If yes - which other hash functions does it apply to and what is the corresponding maximal length?

Comment: Most likely not. See [Is SHA-512 bijective when hashing a single 512-bit block?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/301/is-sha-512-bijective-when-hashing-a-single-512-bit-block). The same arguments apply to SHA-1.

Comment: I don't see any answer there, only assumtions, that it is **most likely not true**, e.g. there is no proof either for it or for the opposite. Unfortunately, i can't comment there.

Comment: With the way we typically construct symmetric primitives the fastest way to prove it, is finding a collision with these properties, and that requires $2^{80}$ work. What's clear is that an ideal 160 bit hashfunction does have collisions with length 20 (with overwhelming probability), and we have not the tiniest amount of evidence suggesting that SHA-1 so broken that it doesn't have this property.

Comment: @SmitJohnth, I don't get why the question CodesInChaos is not acceptable here? Yes, there is no proof, but one does not exist, so intuition is the best that can be given in this case.

Comment: @mikeazo Technically the proof *exists*, but it's very expensive ($2^{80}$ invocations) to find it.

Comment: @CodesInChaos, I would say the proof technique exists but not the proof as no one has computed it. Perhaps I am being pedantic though (or don't completely understand something). On a side note, the $2^{80}$ invocations will not find a collision with probability $1$, right?

Comment: @mikeazo 1) I used *exist* in the mathematical sense, where you can show that something exists, without being able to actually construct it. (If the claim that there are collisions is actually true, then there exists a short proof for their existance) 2) Not with probability 1. You need $2^{160}+1$ in the worst case. But it's quite unlikely it will need more than $2^{90}$ operations.

Comment: @CodesInChaos, I see your point. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: I'm going to close the question for now. Please address why you feel that the question posted by CodesInChaos does not answer your question and flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: I don't see any mathematical proof, ether for or against the assumption. This question is **probably** a duplicate of that, but that question has no answer too. And, not the last reason i want this question to be opened, i can't comment there and can here.

Comment: @SmitJohnth That is because there *is* no mathematical proof. Modern hash functions have structures that aren't very exploitable mathematically, *by design*. The best we can do is either brute-force it and try to find a collision, but this is expensive (it's supposed to be infeasible, actually) or assume that SHA-1 is a perfect random function and use that to calculate the likelihood of bijection, and the duplicate's answers address both these approaches. There simply *is no other known way on a non-broken hash function*.

Comment: I have created a [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7719/chat-about-bijectivity-of-hash-functions) we can use to discuss this.