# Are MD5 possibilities really $2^{128}$?

Tags: algorithm-design, md5

I have a simple question:

Are we certain that the md5 hashing algorithm can produce $2^{128}$ different outputs ?
If so, how ?

Note: Sorry if this has already been asked, I really couldn't find it.

Comment: Related question from StackOverflow: [Do cryptographic hash functions reach each possible value, e.g. are they surjective?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2658601/1285942)

Comment: @mikeazo Thank you very much, that word (surjectivity) helped me find my question : https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/43205/is-it-known-whether-the-md5-algorithm-is-surjective

Comment: That's how it goes some times, just need the right word. Also related [Are common cryptographic hashes bijective when hashing a single block of the same size as the output?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/301/are-common-cryptographic-hashes-bijective-when-hashing-a-single-block-of-the-sam)

Answer (score 1):

MD5 processes a message into a fixed-length output of 128 bits, typically represented as a sequence of 32 hexadecimal digits.

This process is not random, but it’s a so called „pseudo-random“-process (A pseudo-random process is a process that appears to be random but is not 100% random).

There is actually no proof that every hash-value of the MD5-process is reachable for some input, but it is expected to be true.

So MD5 can hash every input to an „arbitrary“ hash-value of 128 bits, bits can be 1 or 0, so $2^{128}$ possible outputs.

Comment: ... and note that there are infinite inputs, so the hash function is very likely to produce each and every value if the output is pseudo-random, otherwise a small bias is clearly present. +1 for answering before it was put on hold :)